# Nativescript Angular - No provider for Router! (RC4 - Router 3.0.0-beta.2)

Tags: angular, router, nativescript

The following Nativescript Angular [application](https://github.com/rrcoolp/test-router-app)- demonstrates navigation using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` - but after to ANGULAR "2.0.0-rc.4" and ROUTER "3.0.0-beta.2", the application fails to load.

ERROR thrown:

```
No provider for Router!


JS: EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 JS: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router! JS: ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: JS: Error: DI Exception JS:     at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (/data/data/org.nativescript.testapp/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:23)
```

Comment: You could review the article and the examples for NativeScript Angular2 navigation article here - https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/navigation-angular.html.

Answer (score 2):

The current official version of nativescript-angular package depends on RC3 @angular code and will probably wont work well with RC4 (there are some internal changes that will break it). However, you can try using the @next builds of `nativescript-angular` that are already migrated to use RC4.

Check [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/363#issuecomment-234475477) for more info on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the actual issue. But I'm guessing, problem is in main.ts.

```
nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent, [AppComponent,HTTP_PROVIDERS,app_globals]);
```

add APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS to it. So it will be:

nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent, [AppComponent,HTTP_PROVIDERS,app_globals, *APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS*]);